# How to remove an item from its position while dragging it in a lazyVgrid using .draggable? Basically how to completely detach the item while drag?

Tags: ios, swiftui, drag-and-drop, swiftui-animation, lazyvgrid

I am implementing drag and drop for items in a lazyVgrid for which I am using .draggable and .dropDestination
Right now while I am dragging an item I see its preview and also the item itself in the grid. I want that only the dragging preview should be visible and the original item should disappear from the grid until I have dropped it at some appropriate position.  [Image showing the preview for the blue dragged item showing both of them appear together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdSJt.jpg)

```
            ScrollView{
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing:10, content: {
                    ForEach(colors, id:\.self){ color in
                        GeometryReader{
                            let size = $0.size
                            
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/25.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                .fill(color.gradient)
                                .draggable(color){
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0)
                                        .fill(.ultraThinMaterial)
                                        .frame(width: size.width, height: size.height)
                                        .onAppear {
                                            draggingItem = color
                                            print(size)
                                        }
                                }
                                .dropDestination(for: Color.self) {items,location in 
                                    return false
                                } isTargeted: { status in
                                    if let draggingItem, status, draggingItem != color {
                                        if let sourceIndex = colors.firstIndex(of: draggingItem),
                                           let destinationIndex = colors.firstIndex(of: color){
                                            withAnimation(.bouncy){
                                                let sourceItem = colors.remove(at: sourceIndex)
                                                colors.insert(sourceItem, at: destinationIndex)
                                                print(colors)
                                            }
                                        }
                                            
                                    }
//                                    print(status)
                                }
                            }
                                .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
```